# social media share specific content out of page

Tags: facebook, share, fbml, fbsdksharekit

I am having some issue with my social media share code.

See my code below:

// I want to share this div (id="maindiv") at facebook on click of facebook share button...

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>    
  <body> 

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=17968886776";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }
    (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>



    <div id="maindiv1" style="border:1px solid blue;width:500px;height:230px">            
        <div  style="border:0px solid red;width:100px;height:80px;float:left;">
         <img src="http://localhost:8080/pushnotification/img/small-icon.png" /><img>
        </div>
        <h1 style="color:blue;font-family:sans-serif;float:left;width:390px;margin-top:10;text-align:center;border:0px solid red;">enterployee.com</h1>
       <div style="border:0px solid red;width:100%;height:120px;float:left;">
        <p style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:15px;">
           Enterployee.com is a employee relationship management tool for enterprise. It’s a fully managed notification platform for employees.
  We have a vision to make organizations more professional and organized. After getting an enterployee account organizations can notify their employees easily and employees can connect with their company in better way.
           </p>

        </div>

        <div style="border:0px solid red;width:80px;height:30px;float:right;">
        <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://localhost:8080/pushnotification/img/small-icon.png" data-layout="button"></div>
        </div>
    </div>                
</body>
```

So the problem is that I have multiple jobs posting in my site and I need to add this share button to each individual divs, not the full page. I have done the coding for full page share but need help in sharing only some part of page or a div.

Comment: _“I have multiple jobs posting in my site”_ – ideally, you would have an individual URL for each of those, that just contains the data for that one job offer. Then you could just share that individual URL to Facebook.

Comment: ok, show for each job post should i use a url..

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="y" data-layout="our urlherebutton"></div>


   (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: it's only for page share on fb but i have need to share specific area or div of page sonam

Comment: please if you know #luschn then tell me